# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'XGBClassifier' on anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost

I am using the python 3.6.2 on Anaconda in ubuntu, and installed xgboost by using "pip install xgboost" and also the method from [here](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#python-package-installation)(set pythonpath to the library), but both can not work, always shows "

> 'module' object has no attribute 'XGBClassifier'

"

Below is my code:

```
cv_params = {'max_depth': [3,5,7], 'min_child_weight': [1,3,5]}
ind_params = {'learning_rate': 0.1, 'n_estimators': 1000, 'seed':0, 'subsample': 0.8, 'colsample_bytree': 0.8, 
             'objective': 'binary:logistic'}
optimized_GBM = GridSearchCV(xgb.XGBClassifier(**ind_params), 
                            cv_params, 
                             scoring = 'accuracy', cv = 5, n_jobs = -1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I already solved this issue by using `conda install -c conda-forge xgboost=0.6a2`

Comment: This works. Do not forget to restart the Kernel after this fix.